# ruby and erb not responding in centos

Tags: ruby, centos, rvm, erb

I've installed ruby with rvm on a centos 6.3 VM and when I attempt to run ruby with no parameters (or erb for that matter) I get no response back, it just sits there.
Running 'ruby' just drops the cursor to the next line like it's waiting for more input or something else to happen. Typing any ruby commands during this time does nothing AFAIK. I do not get any errors, but I'm not exactly sure where to look. I have to control-c to break out of it.

Few interesting things:
(I'm fairly new to linux, so be gentle)

running the command `ruby -v`
gets me:

```
ruby 1.9.3p374 (2013-01-15 revision 38858) [x86_64-linux]
```

so it seems like it's installed

running:

```
echo "puts 'hello'" |ruby
```

gets me:

```
hello
```

I've created a different user and then logged in with that user and the behavior is the same.

I've installed rails and then created a rails app and I can do `rails c` use the rails console

Other notes that may or may not be relevant:
I've recently installed KDE. I did have ruby working before installing KDE but I can't say it was the installation of KDE that messed it up.

I've already uninstalled ruby using rvm and reinstalled, same thing.
Uninstalled rvm and reinstalled.

I've no idea where to go with this or what information would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `irb` to get an interactive session. This is a *REPL,* a Read-Eval-Print Loop.

To see Ruby do something in response to running the interpreter and feeding it standard input interactively, try something like:

```
$ ruby
p :hello
^D
```

If you just type `ruby`, I'm not sure anything will happen until it reads the entire input file ... i.e., sees a Control/D indicating *standard input end-of-file*.

Comment: Thank you. I see that the problem exists between seat and keyboard. irb works just fine...

Answer (score 0):

I believe your looking for `irb` - the interactive Ruby interpreter.

`erb` is an interpreter that expects a file argument.

```
$ erb hello-world.rb
```